# Rails AJAX post form from HTTP side to HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, csrf, same-origin-policy

I'm having a problem submitting an **AJAX** form (it is a sign-up modal form, that ideally, should be available on all of the pages) from HTTP (unsecured) to HTTPS (secured) part of the site.

The problem is - I'm getting status "200 OK", but no actual response is available (hard to debug actually) and nothing happens after it (but it should).

If I do the same request from one of the secured (HTTPS -> HTTPS) pages - it works totally fine.

Also in the log file I see following message: "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity".

I tried skipping this CSRF filter, but no difference.

Can it be fixed somehow, apart from enabling SSL on the entire site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem myself by applying an `after_filter` to corresponding controller actions:

```
def access_control_header
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"] = "*"
end
```

Easy :)